# How to pin an object (as opposed to a file) to and IPFS node?

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-http-client, ipfs-kubo

I am trying to figure out how to pin data to an IPFS node without putting said data into a file. I've read through the kubo docs and am unclear specifically where it refers to the object data argument.

```
const res = await fetch(`${ipfsUrl}/dag/put?pin=true`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ Data: cid, "object data": "multipart/form-data" })
      })
```

This is the request I am currently trying (have tried several variations).

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 400,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 3301.874954223633,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 3301.874954223633,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 40,
      decodedBodySize: 40,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(5) {
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'vary' => [Object],
      'x-content-type-options' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

this is the response Im getting

Answer (score 0):

I believe the kubo RPC API requires a file vs JSON but you can pretty easily turn that data into a file with a few extra lines of code:

```js
const data = JSON.stringify({ Data: cid })
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/json'})
const file = new File([blob], "data.json", { type: 'application/json'})
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append("files", file)

const res = await fetch(`${ipfsUrl}/dag/put?pin=true`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' },
        body: formData
      })
```

Depending on your use case writing to file might be handy for backups not on IPFS, which is similar to how we handle our [pinJSONToIPFS endpoint](https://docs.pinata.cloud/reference/post_pinning-pinjsontoipfs)

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, it is very helpful information, but when I send it up like that, the response I get is unexpected token 'o' no multipart form data is not valid json. Ive messed around with it trying to change certain things but would you happen to know why this is happening?

Comment: I figured it out! Apparently, it doesnt want me to set content type, thanks again for the help